# Web Api OAuth authentication with validating a user

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC 5 + Web Api 2 + Angular application. I have successfully managed to implement OAuth authentication using the Identity framework. When my user submits the log on form I am posting to /Token with the proper request and I am getting the bearer token back and that is all good.

My problem is that I want to insert a step during the authentication process. Currently the authentication process calls the Token endpoint which calls through the Identity framework, and then calls my data class to retrieve the user from the database and then it compares the password. If all checks out it returns a 200 to the client with the bearer token.

What I want is to insert a step that performs an additional check to see if the user has a confirmed email address and that they are not disabled and if either of those checks fail I want to return a 400.

I decompiled the code for the UserManager class and the IIdentityValidator is only executed on create or update. I thought about overriding the Find methods but that doesn't seem right to me as this check should only happen during log on.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints imposed by the Katana OAuth2 implementation for resource owner password flow are imposed to follow the RFC for OAuth2. If you want to give the user feedback on their account or do some UI workflow, then you should consider the OAuth2 implicit flow.

Comment: Any more info you can give me on how to implement an implicit flow?

Comment: This isn't what you want, but it's still useful: http://leastprivilege.com/2014/03/24/the-web-api-v2-oauth2-authorization-server-middlewareis-it-worth-it/